# Reinforcement Learning in 2018, best tips and tricks?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Putting aside things applicable to neural networks such as dropout, l2 regularization, new opitmizers - what are the cool things I should be adding to my Reinforcement Learning algorithm (Q-Learning and SARSA) to make it stronger, in **2018**?

So far, I know these:

1. Experience Replay (gather experiences, then train at once on some of them)
2. Slowly making our network approach the Q-values of a Target Network. The target Network is only cloned sometimes.
3. If our function approximator is RNN and our Memory Bank stores sequences of several timesteps, [after selecting few random sequences from Memory bank, only backpropagate a half of the sequence, without going back to its start](https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-6-partial-observability-and-deep-recurrent-q-68463e9aeefc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Rainbow RL](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.02298.pdf)? It combines all improvements of RL. Apart from structural changes other improvements come from Reward Shaping, Curiosity-driven Learning, RL with Unsupervised Auxiliary tasks and RL with external memory (e.g. Neural Episodic Control, Model-free episodic Control). It's pitty that you leave out from your question Policy Gradients, they are lots of fun :) Happy reading!